# Combining values ​based on conditions, using an Arrayformula | Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, textjoin

What should a function that combines selected values ​​into one using an array function look like?
I would like the function to combine `Unique Nr` if `Id` and `data` are the same.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x1yR2oc2VxUFuijEq-bhLKGgHscnIzDVS0cguIslajk/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&","\ B2:B&" "&C2:C&"♦"}; 
 "select max(Col1) 
  where Col1 <> ',' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2");; 9^9)); "♦")); ",$"; ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for. Is it possible to redo so that the result is without the first column (F)? - only Unique_nr

Comment: @AdOne sure:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&","\ B2:B&" "&C2:C&"♦"}; 
 "select max(Col1) 
  where Col1 <> ',' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2");; 9^9)); "♦")); ",$"; );;2))`

Comment: maybe you know how to apply this whole function only for records where E2: E = TRUE I tried to add filter or if function but it doesn't work properly